# Make span inside <li> clickable with Treeview.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a destination list where I use **[treeview.js](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smoot-Collapsible-Tree-View-Plugin-with-jQuery-TreeViewJS/)**. I have added a `<span></span>` tag inside `<li></li>` and tweaked a little CSS to make it look nicer. My goal is to expand the list by clicking the `<span></span>` tags. However, no matter what I do, I can't make the `<span></span>` tag clickable.

I've tried adding `display:block;` and `display:inline-block;` while adding the width and height but nothing's working.

Here's my CSS:

```
    #tree li>span {
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px 6px;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height: 22px;
    width: 40%;
    padding-left:20px;
    }

    /* TreeJS styling */

    .treeview, .treeview ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    .treeview li {
    text-indent: 1%;
    margin-top:0.2em;
    padding:0.15em 0 0.5em 1.5em;
    line-height: 22px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 24px 24px;
    }

    .treeview li.contains-items {
    /*background-image: url('icons/arrow-left.png');*/
    } 

   .treeview li.contains-items:before {
    content:"\e081" !important;
    font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
    line-height:0.5;
    margin:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 5px;
    }

    .treeview li.items-expanded:before {
    content:"\e082" !important;
    font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
    line-height:0.5;
    margin:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 5px;
    }

    .treeview li.items-expanded {
    /*background-image: url('icons/arrow-down.png');*/
   }

.treeview>li:hover {
cursor: pointer;
background-size: 24px 24px;
}

.treeview span.has-node-icon {
text-indent: 2%;
margin-top:0.2em;
padding:0.15em 0 0.5em 2.0em;
line-height: 22px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 24px 24px;
}

.treeview span:not(span.has-node-icon):hover{
background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 0.7);
}
```

No changes were made in the js file of treeview.

This might seem like an 'easy' question but I've been working on it for hours now[image].

**EDIT:**
I have created a simple **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1b1s7mq/11/)**.
But you can also see it in action **[here](http://test.forexcargo.us/apps/oss/calculator)**.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's hard to say.. can you try to make a jsfiddle for just this part?

Comment: Are you saying that you actually cannot click on the text area (on the left). That you are *only* able to click in the blank white space to the right? If so, how are you generating the list content? All we see is the css styling, not the generation.

Comment: Hi @animake, I added a jsfiddle link and my link so you can see where it is. Please see the edit in my post. Thanks!

Comment: @IncredibleHat please see the links I added so you can see it in action. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Treeview.js is probably binding the click only to the `<li>`. Maybe you could accomplish the same thing without the `<span>` and just apply the same style to the `<li>` like this:

```css
.treeview>li { /* <-- previously .treeview span {... */
  text-indent: 2%;
  margin-top:0.2em;
  padding:0.15em 0 0.5em 2.0em;
  line-height: 22px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 24px 24px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Mathis, I added your code snippet but it's not working. The main text is not clickable when I used your code.

Comment: Could you post the HTML you're using?

Comment: I have edited my post @Tim Mathis. I added the link on where it is exactly so you could see everything. Thanks!

Comment: Your best route is probably to remove the `<span>` completely and just style the `<li>` with the `border`, `border-radius`, etc.

Comment: This is what happens when I transfer the css to `<li></li>` -> https://snag.gy/nKOUPv.jpg

Comment: Be sure you're using `.treeview>li` and not `.treeview li` so that all the `<li>` children don't get styled.